# AMPscript HTTPPost2 Parameters

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm a bit lost with the HTTPPost2 function. According to [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/httppost2.htm), the fifth parameter is:

> used to contain string representation for the status of the HTTP request, such as OK.

But this isn't the case. It returns a **rowset**. I'd really like to find out what the field names that are used in the rowset are, so I can view their values.

I note that depending on the URL I use for my POST request, the number of rows in the rowset changes.

Does anyone have any ideas what field values are used?

### Sample Request

```
%%[
var @payload, @postRequest, @response, @responseRows

set @payload = '{  
   "Order Number":10110113,
   "First Name":"Simon",
   "Last Name":"Sausage",
   "Amount":{  
      "Order Subtotal":120,
      "VAT":20,
      "Shipping":0,
      "Order Total":120
   }
}'

set @postrequest = HTTPPost2("https://httpbin.org/post","application/json", @payload, true, @response, @responseRows)
]%%

status code: %%=v(@postrequest)=%%

response: %%=v(@response)=%%

responseRows: %%=v(@responseRows)=%%

responseRowCount: %%=RowCount(@responseRows)=%%
```

### Sample Output

The request returns the status code, response payload and rowset.

The following response has been abbreviated for display purposes.

```
status code: 200

response: {"args":{}, "data":"{...}", "files":{}, "form":{  }, "headers":{...}, "json":{"Amount":{"Order Subtotal":120, "Order Total":120, "Shipping":0, "VAT":20 }, "First Name":"Simon", "Last Name":"Sausage", "Order Number":10110113 } }

responseRows: System.Data.DataRow[]

responseRowCount: 10
```

Answer (score 1):

I Guess the `Platform.Function.ParseJSON();` will do the trick!
Not sure what is expected here, but as per my below code I able to get the desired token from the rowset received.

```
<!-- Processing page : START -->
%%[
   /*Generating the AccessToken using client id and secret key*/
   VAR @callstatus, @response
   SET @payload = '{"client_id": "xxxxx", "client_secret": "xxxxxx", "grant_type": "client_credentials"}'
   SET @accessToken = HTTPPost2("https://xxxxxxx.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token", "application/json", @payload, True, @callstatus, @response)
   ]%% 

<script runat="server">
/*Framing the API content and extracting only access token from the above "@callstatus" */
   Platform.Load("core", "1");

   var accessTok = Variable.GetValue("@callstatus");
   var response_ = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(accessTok);
   var accessToken_ = response_.access_token;
   Variable.SetValue("@accessToken_",accessToken_);

   Variable.SetValue("@token_",'Bearer '+accessToken_); 

   </script>

 Callstatus   =   %%=v(@callstatus)=%% 
 accessToken_   =    %%=v(@accessToken_)=%% 
 token_   =   %%=v(@token_)=%% 
<!-- Processing page : END -->
```

Note: **Kindly replace Client ID, Client secrete and subdomain in URL**